# how to access key/value pairs from json() object?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm calling an external service and I get the returned domain object like this:

```
var domainObject = responseObject.json();
```

This converts the response object into a js object. I can then easily access a property on this object like this

```
var users = domainObject.Users
```

Users is a collection of key/value pairs like this:

```
1: "Bob Smith"
2: "Jane Doe"
3: "Bill Jones"
```

But CDT shows users as Object type and users[0] returns undefined. So how can I get a handle to the first item in the collection? I'm assuming that some type of type cast is needed but not sure how I should go about doing this

**UPDATE**

Here is one way I could access the values:

```
//get first user key
Object.keys(responseObject.json().Users)[0]

//get first user value
Object.values(responseObject.json().Users)[0]
```

But I need to databind through ng2 so I was hoping for a simpler way like this:

```
<div>
    <div *ngFor="let user of users">
        User Name: {{user.value}}
        <br>
    </div>
</div>
```

Maybe I should just create a conversion function in my ng2 component which converts the object into what I need before setting the databinding variable?

Comment: Have you tried `users['1']`?

Comment: Javascript objects are not intrinsically ordered, so what is meant by the "first" item?

Comment: @Lixus - I can access the items by a specific value like you mentioned.  I should have used id's like 123, 456, 789, etc.  Basically the id's could be anything and my goal is simply to access the first item in the collection. James - I'm just looking to access the first item in the collection.  I don't care about the specific item that's accessed.  Just trying to pick off the value and that type of operation would generally be done in coding as users[0]

Comment: What is CDT ?  What does console.log(users) show ?

Comment: CDT = "Chrome Dev Tools."  The console shows an Object with a collection of the user key/value pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

So after scouring through a few docs I found the "newish" `Object.entries()` javascript function. [You can read about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). Pretty cool.

Anyways, give this a try. I am ashamed to say that I don't have time to test it, but it should get you going in the right direction.

```
usersArray = []

// Turn Users object into array of [key, value] sub arrays.
userPairs = Object.entries(users);

// Add the users back into an array in the original order.
for (i=0; i < userPairs; i++) {
    usersArray.push(_.find(userPairs, function(userPair) { return userPair[0] == i }))
}
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I would use either [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) or [lodash](https://lodash.com/) to do this. Both are super helpful libraries in terms of dealing with data structures and keeping code to a minimum. I would personally use the `_.values` function in lodash. [Read more about it here.](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#values). Then you could use `users[0]` to retrieve the first item.

The only caveat to this is that lodash doesn't guarantee the iteration sequence will be the same as it is when the object is passed in.

```
users = _.values(users);
console.log(users[0]);
```

Comment: thanks josh. that seems like a good shortcut. unfortunately, I need to maintain the order of users b/c the values are sorted by user last name. For example:  [{456: "Jack Smith"}{123: "Bill Watson"}]. therefore, it would be difficult to resort on the client side

Comment: I updated my post with a function that returns an array of key value pairs. From there you should be able to re-sort it using the correct index on each key/value pair array.

Comment: yep this will easily give me the first item in the array for this scenario:
Object.entries(users)[0]

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
let user= this.users.find(() => true)
```

This should return the "first" one.

Comment: thanks deb but I tried your example and it returns undefined :\

Comment: Hmmm. I *did* take the time to test it and it worked for me. But it looks like you already found an answer ... so no need to follow up.

Answer (score 0):

If your initial object is just a plain object, how do you know it is sorted. Property members are not sorted, ie: looping order is nor guaranteed. I´d extract the user names into an array and the sort that array by the second word. This should work (as long as surnames are the second word, and only single spaces are used as separators).

```
var l=[];
for(var x in users) {
 push.l(users[x]);
}
var l1=l.sort ( (a,b) => return a.split(" ")[1]<b.split(" ")[1]);
```

Comment: is there an arrow function or some type of shortcut for that?  something I could execute through a CDT Watch?